# Fortrabbit Worker + IronMq + Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, ironmq, fortrabbit

I'm looking at the example of the Worker+IronMq.

http://fortrabbit.com/docs/in-depth/workers/scheduler-example

The question is how can I call a specific service in Symfony2 from the worker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [stanlemon/bernard-bundle](https://github.com/stanlemon/bernard-bundle) integrates bernardphp.com into symfony. Bernard supports different backends such as:

- Predis / PhpRedis
- Amazon SQS
- Iron MQ
- Doctrine DBAL

Here is an example how to use your service:

```
<service id="acme.demo.message_handler.api_update" class="Acme\DemoBundle\Updater\ApiUpdateMessageHandler">
    <argument type="service" id="acme.demo.updater.api"/>
    <tag name="bernard.receiver"/>
</service>
```

Comment: Thanks. Already looking into this. Bernard has the following code for the consumer. I assume it goes into the worker. Where should I get a `$container`from?


`$serviceResolver = new \Bernard\Symfony\ContainerAwareServiceResolver($container); $serviceResolver->register('SendNewsletter', 'my.service.id');
`